# HDD Power On Count Increase rapidly

Tags: hard-drive

My old hard disk before faces a lot of problem, the things inside of it are corrupted and sometimes it is undetectable I thought it is the hard disk problem so I bought a new one.

Old Hard Disk:
[image: Old Hard Disk]

When the new hard disk arrived, it worked fine for a day but the next day the power on count increased rapidly.

New Hard Disk:
[image: New Hard Disk]

Can I know what is causing this problem and how can I fix it?

Its an internal additional storage

Comment: Is this an internal OS drive, internal additional storage drive or external USB drive?

Comment: Internal additional storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Check the power saving settings on your PC, they may be too aggressive. You should decide if the lifetime of the disk is more important than saving power.

Comment: the power saving option is on "balanced" tho

Comment: Yes, but you can disable it completely to see if the power cycles stop.

Comment: So, I tried to download something from steam, it was working fine at first then after a minute the disk drive suddenly dissapear from "This PC"

After shut down and reopen the disk is appeared

Comment: So i tried to redownload it again, when I attempt to pause the download the disk remain 100% and steam, folder of the disk drive and crystaldisk all became not responding for 5 minute, and the disk dissapeared from the pc again.

Comment: Perhaps you should tell us something about the PC itself?  It seems your problems are the same with the new disk as they were with the old one?

Comment: What should I say about?? (Sorry im really bad)
The problem are similar as they both suddenly not detected by windows, just that old disk file after restart would get corrupted easily but the new disk are less likely to corrupt the files.

Comment: AMD Ryzen 3 1200 Quad-Core 3.10 GHz  
A320M PRO-VD PLUS (MS-7B38)  
8GB DDR4 RAM  
GTX 1050TI,4GB VRAM

Comment: Every time I was in a game loading screen it takes like a long time and the power on count increase by 1 when it finish loading, is it normal?

Comment: Yes, as long as power-saving is enabled.  Did you disable it?  PSU specs?

Comment: I don't really see an option to disable the power-saving for my pc so I changed the power plan to High Performance :/

Comment: Perhaps: change the sata cable and use another sata connector, your MB has 4 of them.  Again: PSU specifications?

Comment: Sorry didnt see that its Cougar SL 500, 500W

Comment: I just had a look on a Windows 10 system - I never use it - and under energy management I found advanced settings where I could determine when to stop the hard disk.  I suggest you have a better look.

Comment: Where is it? I don't really see the option

Comment: Is it big enough for you to see?

Comment: What thing is big?

Comment: Consider the finger pointing towards the moon...... don't watch the finger or you'll miss all that heavenly glory - Bruce Lee.   Please check my answer.

Comment: OOO didn't see that, its on 20 minute